# POSTing via RoR getting back JSON, now what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, forms, post

OK, I'm totally new to Ruby on Rails.  I created a form that posts to an external widget that returns JSON.  So I have this form:

```
<%= form_for :email, :url => 'http://XXX.XX.XXX.212/widgetapi.0.1.php', :html => {:class => "new_email"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :value => "Your email address...", :class => "text", :id => "email", :name => 'email',  
    :onFocus => "change(this,'#222222'); this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;",
    :size => "26" %>  
      <%= f.hidden_field :apiKey, :id => "apiKey", :name => 'apiKey', :value => "ABC123" %>  
     <%= f.hidden_field :lrDomain, :id => "lrDomain", :name => 'lrDomain', :value => "signup.triplingo.com" %>  
     <%= f.hidden_field :urlPrefix, :id => "refCodeUrl", :name => 'refCodeUrl', :value => "http://signup.website.com/" %>  
    <%= f.hidden_field :ref_code, :id => 'ref_code', :name => 'ref_code', :value => @referralid %>  
    <%= submit_tag "Enter To Win", :class => "button-positive submit" %>  
    <% end %>
```

Which works.  Now I get back a JSON response that is:

```
({"email":"testing@testing2.com","reflink":"fi1ts","newuser":true})
```

Ok now the result it the browser sits on the response page with the JSON.

I'm guessing I need to do something with the @response in the controller, but I'm not sure what.  All I want to do is if that "newuser" is true, provide them a success page.  If false, go to an error page.

Thanks.

Comment: What API is that? I have a pretty strong feeling that your server should be sending the API call, not the client.

Comment: It's a service we're using for link tracking...  The user provides their email address and gets a reference code.  So I have a web form that posts to the php widget to generate the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change that form, so that it will send request to your controller. In that controller you should do API Call with parameters from a form(using for example Curb: https://github.com/taf2/curb or Net/http: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html). Then You can parse result in JSON and show user correct page.

So:

1) User send request to YOUR application

2) YOUR application make request to http://XXX.XX.XXX.212/widgetapi.0.1.php using data from user

3) YOUR application receives JSON, and check if newuser is true.

4) If it is true action render success page, otherwise it render error page.

Comment: So let me regurgitate this in a bit more detail to make sure I got it.    1) I modify my form to post to say the submit action:   <% form_tag(:action => 'submit') do %>  2) Then use curb to send a POST to the widget URL.   3)We'll then receive back the JSON, check the flag     4) Then render the correct result page     All this happens in the same action in the controller or is there a more 'standard' way to do this?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. All this happen in the same action in the controller. This is standard way to do this.